# Which way is better to assign/create properties to an object via constructor?

Tags: javascript, oop, object

Which is better to do? When passing or changing properties values?

I'll explain better in the two examples below:

```
// Example 1:
var Object = function(_prop1, _prop2, _prop3) {
    this.prop1 = _prop1;
    this.prop2 = _prop2;
    this.prop3 = _prop3;
}

var foo = new Object(
    11111111,
    22222222,
    33333333
);

//Example 2:
var Object = function() {
    this.prop1 = null;
    this.prop2 = null;
    this.prop3 = null;
}

var foo = new Object();

foo.prop1 = 11111111;
foo.prop2 = 22222222;
foo.prop3 = 33333333;
```

I'd like to know which has better performance or which is better and why.

Comment: Both of your examples have a syntax error. Should be `this.prop1 = whatever`, not `this.prop1: whatever`.

Comment: *a* , as its the only one working...

Comment: yes sorry. now is corrected

Comment: mmm actually there's not much help from that question. but I get the idea. thanks all.